# jQuery Slider doesn't work with saved images

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add a jQuery slider to my website, but for some reason it doesn't display images that are saved on my computer only images from a website.

The code is below.  As you can see the first element on the list is an image from a file, which is located at /Users/Dom/Desktop/NewWebsite/images/jam.jpg.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>UnSlider</title>
        <style>
            body, html {
                padding:0px;
                margin: 0px;
            }
            .banner { 
                position: relative; 
                width: 100% !important; 
                overflow: auto; 
                padding: 0px;
                margin: 0px;
            }
            .banner ul {
                padding: 0px;
                margin: 0px;
            }
            .banner li { 
                list-style: none; 
                padding: 0px;
                margin: 0px;
            }
            .banner ul li { 
                float:left;
                padding: 0px;
                margin: 0px;
                min-height: 350px;
                -webkit-background-size: 100% auto;
                -moz-background-size: 100% auto;
                -o-background-size: 100% auto;
                -ms-background-size: 100% auto;
                background-size: 100% auto;
                background-position-y: -75px;
                box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="banner">
            <ul>
                <li style="background-image: url("../images/jam.jpg");"></li>
                <li style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/1400x400');"></li>
                <li style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/1400x400');"></li>
                <li style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/1400x400');"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://unslider.com/unslider.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.banner').unslider({
                    speed: 500,               //  The speed to animate each slide (in milliseconds)
                    delay: 5000,              //  The delay between slide animations (in milliseconds)
                    keys: true,               //  Enable keyboard (left, right) arrow shortcuts
                    dots: false,               //  Display dot navigation
                    fluid: false              //  Support responsive design. May break non-responsive designs
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you want to share the path to the folder you have this html file and the folder, where you have the images, that will be helpful to help you.

lets say your html file is located in:/Users/Dom/Desktop/NewWebsite to access the image, you do this: 
`<li style="background-image: url("images/jam.jpg");"></li>` or 
`<li style="background-image: url("images/jam.jpg");"></li>` in your example
 2 dots(..) means go one folder back, while your image is in the same folder. and you can also do as follow: 
`<li style="background-image: url("./images/jam.jpg");"></li>` 
1 dot(.) means there is a folder called images, in the same folder, go inside it and find me a picture called jam.jpg hope it helps good luck –

Comment: Thanks, I edited my original post.  The file is located at /Users/Dom/Desktop/NewWebsite/images/jam.jpg.  It's a mac if it matters.

Comment: Thanks! I changed it to 'images/jam.jpg' and it works